# Cartoon from the 80s or 90s about a dream master?

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I can't remember many details but I know it was shown in the 90s,  but looked like it was made in the 80s. It aired on ITV in the UK , and the theme tune was very serene.  The lyrics were something about "wild imagination".

The show had a good faction that dealt with dreams,  and there was a dream master of some sort who was a really seen Dumbledore/gandalf style wizard.

There was an evil side who may have been in a volcano and dealt with nightmares.

The intro/outro may have had dreams appearing in bubbles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [**The Dreamstone**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dreamstone)

> *Better than a dream
>
>   **Stranger than my wild imagination**
>
>   If this is a real sensation, It's better than a dream.
>
>   Higher than the moon,
>
>   Hazy like a beautiful illusion.
>
>   Crazy and in confusion,
>
>   And better than a dream.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Better than a Dream lyrics](http://thedreamstone.wikia.com/wiki/Better_Than_A_Dream)</sup></sub>

Comment: The song writer is Katie Melua’s manager and there is a video out there if her doing a live cover of it.

Comment: @Darren - **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OdbBm3dYToc**

Comment: Was just about to post that link myself!